# Can't iterate CSV Reader object due to Encode Error

Tags: python, csv

I'm working with a 3rd party API which returns the data as a Python CSV Reader object.

This is how the response CSV Reader object looks like:

```
dir(data)
Out[67]: 
['__class__',
'__delattr__',
'__doc__',
'__format__',
'__getattribute__',
'__hash__',
'__init__',
'__iter__',
'__new__',
'__reduce__',
'__reduce_ex__',
'__repr__',
'__setattr__',
'__sizeof__',
'__str__',
'__subclasshook__',
'dialect',
'line_num',
'next']

type(data)
Out[68]: _csv.reader
```

When I tried to read this object, I got the following error:

```
l = list(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-69-587d9010ea41>", line 1, in <module>
l = list(data)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 88: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is this something I can fix from my end or I have to ask the vendor to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Pretty sure the vendor has to fix it. By the time a `reader` is created, the file has already been opened without proper encoding. Not much you can do at that point.

Comment: Thank you. Will contact the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try in Python 3.4?  That might solves the problem.